Third element out of page body
The third element is out of my body when I inspect it
When I delete this child element not go out of parent but I want to change position so I use css but it is still a problem


.rac {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 700px solid #436850;

}
#kshatriya{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
#kshat-text{
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    
}

#kshat-text2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
}
<body class="bg-dark">
    <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar" data-bs-root-margin="0px 0px -40%" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example bg-body-tertiary " tabindex="0">


      <div class=" item position-realative" id="scrollspyHeading1">
        <div class="rac" align="right">
          <div id="kshat-text">NZ-666 <br> Kshatriya</div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/kasht.png" id="kshatriya" alt="kshatriya">
    
      <div id="kshat-text2">XDDD</div>
      </div>
</body>




Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a very poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out LearnLayout.com

What is your expectation from position: absolute; left: -100%;?

for changing position?

What layout were you trying to create (ideally [edit] your question to show an image of the desired layout in the question body)?
